# Dynamic content block octobercms

Tags: php, octobercms

How do I render dynamic content block?

```
{% content 'variable.html' %}
```

- variable is a placeholder for other contents to render.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
//php section
public function onStart(){
    $this['some_content_variable'] = 'variable.htm';
}
==
{% content some_content_variable %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works in case you need to concatenate folder path:

```
{% content 'path/folder/' ~ some_content_variable ~ '.htm' %}
```

PS: You can ommit '.htm' if you want.